# How to link agentbreed1 to agentbreed2 one-on-one?

Tags: netlogo

I got 2 large sets of agentbreeds1 (villagers) and an equal amount of agentbreeds2 (houses). I am attempting to link these two together on a one-to-one ratio. So far I tried to do this by the following line, but I am not sure whether it does so correctly:

```
ask villagers [
  create-link-with one-of other houses
 ]
```

Just for clarity, if I have villager1 it may only connect to one house that does not have any link to another villager already.

Hopefully one of the bright folks here can help me further!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty close, but since you have no constraint saying something like "you may only create a link with a house that has no villager already" you will end up with some houses that have multiple villagers linked and some houses that have no villagers linked. All you have to do to correct that is to include that constraint, such that villagers may only link to a house that is not already linked:

```
  ask villagers [
    create-link-with one-of houses with [ not any? link-neighbors ]
  ]
```

To check that it worked, you can either visually inspect the links or run some variation of the lines below:

```
  ask turtles [ 
    if count link-neighbors != 1 [
      show ("I am not linked to just one turtle.")
    ]
  ]
```

If any turtle is not linked to another, or is linked to more than one, it will print the line in quotes.

Comment: If it is not to much to ask, how can I use the link to make the villager to return to their house?

Comment: Maybe something like `ask villagers [ move-to one-of link-neighbors ]`?